# Why is the id of an element undefined when properly shown in console using DOMNodeInserted?

Tags: javascript, youtube, tampermonkey

Im trying to do something when a new chat message appears on a youtube live stream in a tampermonkey script.

Im using a DOMNodeInserted event on a div with the id "chat-messages"

The problem is: im not able to get the id of the element (undefined) but it's getting printed in the console correctly. Its also not possible to get the class attribute using jquery.

Code:

```
$("#chat-messages").on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {

  var VanillaElement = e.target;
  var JqueryElement = $(VanillaElement);


  if(JqueryElement.is("yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer")){

    console.log("added chat message");
    console.log(VanillaElement);
    console.log(VanillaElement.id);
    console.log(JqueryElement.attr("class"));

  }



});
```

Here is a screenshot for better understanding:

[image: output]

Comment: Maybe try `console.dir` instead of `console.log` so you can see the element as an object. That helps sometimes to understand what is really going on.

Comment: Have you tried `JqueryElement.id`?

Comment: So if the code you posted with the `console.log()` calls is *working*, where is the code that *doesn't* work?

Comment: @Pointy im just want the id. I dont want to print the element into the console :)

Comment: Well if `console.log(VanillaElement.id)` works then you are getting the id. Your question doesn't make much sense unless you explain how it is that you think you "can't get" the id value.

Comment: console.log(VanillaElement.id) -> undefined

Comment: Because it's not a standard DOM element, it may be the case that you'll have to use `VanillaElement.getAttribute("id")`

Comment: VanillaElement.getAttribute("id") -> null

Comment: I suspect the ID is being added dynamically later. The console is lazy about displaying objects, so you're seeing the full element after the ID is added.

Comment: Why do you need the ID? You have a reference to the element, just use that.

Comment: The basic problem is that the node is being inserted, then the `id` and `class` attributes are being added. Your code runs after the insert, but before the attributes.

Comment: @Barmar That could be. If i had the id i could use $(id) to get information out of the element. For Example i need to find a div inside the message like this: JqueryElement.find("#content").html() but that is undefined too

Comment: Your code is running before anything has been added to the node, that's why everything is undefined. You need to save the variable and use it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running before the ID and class are added to the element. The YouTube code must be inserting the element and then adding the attributes, so your code runs in between. See [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) for the reason why you see the attributes when you log `VanillaElement`.

The best solution is to not use the `id`, just save `VanillaElement` and `jqueryElement` for later use. If you want to see the ID, you could add a delay before showing it.

```js
$("#chat-messages").on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  var VanillaElement = e.target;
  var JqueryElement = $(VanillaElement);
  if (JqueryElement.is("yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer")) {
    console.log("added chat message");
    console.log(VanillaElement);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(VanillaElement.id);
      console.log(JqueryElement.attr("class"));
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yup.Thats it. Also found it out with the help of your comment.